# Iterate through a string forwards and backwards, extracting alternating characters

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm studying python and there's a lab I can't seem to crack. We have a line e.g. `shacnidw`, that has to be transformed to `sandwich`. I somehow need to iterate with a `for` loop and pick the letters with odd indexes first, followed by backward even indexes. Like pick a letter with index 1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2.

It looks pretty obvious to use a list or slices, but we aren't allowed to use these functions yet. I guess the question is just how do I do it?

Comment: If you understand slices, you should be able to understand index accessing

Comment: Start with `for i, letter in enumerate (mystring): print (i, letter)` and see if that suggests an approach

Comment: You might also want to look at the step parameter of the range function

Comment: Could you elaborate on the conditions of the lab? Is only a single for loop allowed?

Comment: Please note that the first index of the string is 0, not 1. I do not see a way to do this problem with a single simple (i.e. no additional decision logic) for loop.

Comment: We're allowed to use as many for loops as we need, so probably two loops with a step of 2 should definitely work. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I am understanding your question right. Check the below code.

```
s = 'shacnidw'
s_odd = ""
s_even = ""
for i in range(len(s)):
  if i%2 == 0:
    s_even += s[i]
for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
  if i%2 == 1:
    s_odd += s[i]

print(s_even + s_odd)
```

I hope it might help.

Comment: You can skip the modulo and do `range(0,len(s),2)`, for example

Comment: @JohnKugelman Shucks, I guess I won't post `[print(starting_string[i*2 if i*2<len(starting_string) else -(i-int(len(starting_string)/2))*2-int(not len(starting_string) % 2)],end='') for i in range(len(starting_string))]` as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

Programming is all about decomposing complex problems into simpler ones. Try breaking it down into smaller steps.

1. First, can you generate the numbers 1,3,5,7 in a `for` loop?
2. Next, can you generate 8,6,4,2 in a second loop?

Tackling those two steps ought to get you on the right track.

Comment: nailed it! that's what i've come up with:
`line = input('Enter an encrypted word:  ')
for i in range(0, len(line), 2):
  print(line[i], end = '')


for n in range(len(line)-1, 0, -2):
  print(line[n], end = '')`

Thank you again, the advice is really helpful, glad you haven't sent me an entire code too!

Answer (score 2):

Your text looks to be in a specific pattern that can be achieved using the following syntax.

> 1, 3, 5, 7     : for n in range(1, size, 2)  : steps of 2 in forward direction
>
> 8, 6, 4, 2 : for m in range(size, 0, -2) : steps of 2 in reverse direction

By building the string with the above indices we can easily arrive at the intended result.

```
string = 'shacnidw'
result = ''
size = len(string) - 1

for n in range(0, size, 2):
    result += string[n]

for m in range(size, 0, -2):
    result += string[m]

print(result)
```

**Result**

```
sandwich
```

Comment: thank you! That is exactly what I've been looking for. I appreciate your help a lot.